# Endeca navigation engine not able to process the request

Tags: java, navigation, runtime-error, endeca

We are using endeca in our project.There is an single endeca application which is running fine.All the machines are pointing to that application and working fine.But in one of the machine after some time.It is throwing ENEException saying that endeca navigation engine not able to process the request.We are not able to replicate that,but this is happening four times a day.As a temporary solution we need to restart the application(web)  server on that machine and everything is fine.We are not able to figure out it.

Comment: Without much more detail on your configuration nobody here is going to be able to help.  Your best bet is to find an Endeca support forum and ask there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a network related issue but it's hard to say with out further details. 
You can try: https://endecacommunity.com/

Which is an excellent Endeca support forumn

Comment: it was really a network issue related to proxy settings in application.Thank a lot for link.

Comment: @JagdevSingh - Could you elaborate on the network issue you faced? We are facing the same "Navigation Engine unable to process request" error couple time a day and then it resolved on its own

Comment: @user1187958 : It was due to some network firewall configuration. Any request passed through this firewall was blocked. It was identified by network team. It was network mis configuration